# React - Fill data before api call?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rest

I tried to call some rest API, but I got some issue.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

So here's my code:

```
class MovieDetailViewer extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        movieResponse: {}, // wont work
        movieResponse: {
            "id": 1,
            "barcode": "000-000-003",
            "name": "Django Unchained",
            "fsk": "FSK_18",
            "lend": false,
            "deleted": false,
            "genre": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Western"
            },
            "source": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Blu-Ray"
            }
        } // will work
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('apiurltogetmovie')
        .then((response) = > response.json())
        .then(responseJson = > {
            this.setState({ movieJsonResponse: responseJson.movie });

        });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <MovieDetails
                movie={this.state.movieJsonResponse}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
}

class MovieDetails extends React.Component {
render() {
    const movie = this.props.movie;

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{movie.name}</h1>
            <h2>{movie.gerne.name} - {movie.source.name}</h2>
            <p>
                {movie.comment}
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

It looked like there was a problem with JSON response but if initialize `movieResponse` with some default JSON it works.
At google I cant find any react example where the state is initialize with some value. Whats the best practice here?

So I am not sure why `gerne.name` is `undefinied`. If I log the JSON response to console it will be fine.

Comment: Should `gerne` be `genre`? If the API misspells this, then your code won't complain, but it will be helpful for human readers to fix this.

Comment: because api calls are async, also `componentDidMount` will get called after initial rendering, so first time `movie.gerne` will be undefined, and it is throwing error when you are trying to access name of undefined.

Comment: make sure `gerne` or `source` objects available inside movie and has name field

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that before the API call in `MovieDetailViewer` finishes, `MovieDetails` is rendered. But, since the response is not available, `movieResponse` is still equal the initial value, which in this case is an empty object. Thus, when attempting to access `movie.genre.name`, since `movie` is empty, `genre` will be undefined and `name` unable to be accessed. To fix this, you should only render `MovieDetails` once the response is available:

```
class MovieDetailViewer extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            movieResponse: null
        }
    }

    ...

    render() {
        return (this.state.movieJsonResponse) ? (
            <div>
                <MovieDetails movie={this.state.movieJsonResponse} />
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div className="loader">loading...</div>
        );
    }
}
```

It is worth noting that your check should likely be more thorough than this, and involve another property on the state describing the current status of the query (querying, success, error, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Best practices that can be used here:

1. Use prop-types to force props to be the same type you expect for.
2. Validate object inner fields, for example: `movie && movie.name.`
3. Use conditional render, for example `{ movie && movie.name && <h1>{movie.name}</h1>}`